# SVN Repository - can checkout but commit gives a timeout

Tags: apache, svn

I have configured a svn server and I can the checkout with no issue. But when I try commit, it takes long time and gives a "connection time out" error in Tortoise svn client. Does anyone have an idea how to resolve or where to check. seems this is a permission issue and I believe the user that I used has required write permission to the server.

Error

[image]

Comment: There is a apache httpd server in front of your svn server? WIth mod_dav?

Comment: Hi Joaa, Yes there is a apache server. Below httpd-vhosts.conf configurations <Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /home/svn/repositories
   SVNListParentPath On
   AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/svn/.svn-policy-file
   AuthName "SVN Repositories"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /home/svn/.svn-auth-file
   Require valid-user
   #order allow,deny
   #   #Allow from all
</Location>

Answer (score 0):

> seems this is a permission issue and I believe the user that I used
>   has required write permission to the server.

This is not a permission issue. You have to check firewalls and your server configuration.

> Does anyone have an idea how to resolve or where to check.

No. This is just a timeout error. You should revise your server configuration and check firewalls. There is a chance that your firewall rejects certain HTTP requests.

Comment: thank you for your input. what do you mean by firewall. I have disabled firewall in server(iptables: Firewall is not running.) I have disabled SElinux also. please advise.

Comment: Also I can navigate to the http url through web browser.

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Kaz Sorry, the only advise I can give now is to check basic connectivity to the server. IP interface, ports, server bindings, the URL that you use to access the server, firewalls, etc. There has to be something very simple that prevents you from accessing the repository.

Comment: Thanks @bahrep I will check .Thing is even when I run import/co commands inside the server **svn import -m "Initial import" ~/svn-import http://172.25.72.64/svn/test_REPO/ --username test** is timeout with error code **svn: E175012: Connection timed out**.